# Why hydrogen lines are less visible in the Sun spectrum than in supernovae clouds?

Tags: astrophysics, spectroscopy, stars, hydrogen, supernova

Supernovae clouds are very colorful, and if I trust documentaries I watched, the colors are due to excitation of elements, as in fireworks. Since the Sun is mostly made of hydrogen, I suppose those lines should be very apparent but they are not so much, its light looking like a blackbody radiation. What contributes to the rest of the spectrum up to the point it masks hydrogen lines?

Comment: It's a bad idea to rush to accept an answer. The answer by Maury Markowitz that you accepted is completely wrong.

Comment: Define rush? And how do I know an answer is wrong? I am not a teacher.

Comment: There *are* emission lines of hydrogen coming from the (relatively thin and tenuous) solar chromosphere, but these are hard to see because they're usually lost in the glare of the blackbody emission from the (denser, opaque) photosphere, which lies under the chromosphere.

Comment: @Exocytosis: Usually it's a good idea to wait a day or two, or wait until there have been multiple answers and people have upvoted or downvoted some. If you don't have the expertise yourself to figure out whether an answer is right or wrong, then you can use the community's help: wait for things to sort themselves out in comments and voting. In this particular case, I would suggest that you undo your acceptance of Maury Markowitz's answer, which is completely wrong for the reasons given in the comments. Your acceptance of it means that it gets listed first, so people will see it and be misled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sun's spectrum is a blackbody spectrum with absorption lines superimposed. The blackbody spectrum comes from the photosphere, which is the highest elevation at which the sun is opaque. It becomes opaque because it's ionized to form a plasma. A plasma is opaque because it has free charges that interact strongly with electromagnetic waves and absorb their energy. The spectrum is a continuous blackbody spectrum rather than an emission spectrum because it's a dense plasma. Discrete emission and absorption spectra are typical of thin gases composed mainly of neutral atoms or molecules.

The absorption lines in the sun are created by layers farther out in which the gas is not ionized and less dense.

Comment: How does a dense plasma produces a broader spectrum? More precisely, what processes generate the various wavelengths? I know that various geometric aspects of molecules produce different lines like vibrational or rotational spectrometry study. Is it that particles in the plasma form ensemble antennas of some sort?

Comment: *Is it that particles in the plasma form ensemble antennas of some sort?* Yes, that's a good description. If the plasma is dense and thermalized, then their velocities and accelerations are continuously varying, so they don't have any definite frequency. (Their fourier spectrum is continuous.)

Answer (score -1):

> What contributes to the rest of the spectrum up to the point it masks
>   hydrogen lines?

It's basically due to the optics.

In the case of the sun, you're seeing the energy of the gas in the outer shell. This is highly random, moving in all directions and over a huge distribution of speeds. So everything is being blurred out in frequency by Doppler shifting, which is why...

> its light looking like a blackbody radiation

In the case of a supernova remnant, you're looking at a bubble of hot gas caused by the outward moving particles shock-heating the interstellar medium when it hits it. So, in this case, in any one area of the cloud, you're seeing particles that are moving at a much more limited range of speeds. This is also why you see a sort of color shift, notice that the crab nebula looks redder at the edges than the center.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. So the doppler effect produces the broadening of the lines? But arent there very lower frequencies, like radiowaves produced by the sun? Are they also due to doppler?

Comment: I don't think this is right at all. The blackbody spectrum is produced in deeper regions, and the outer regions produce absorption lines.

Comment: That is definitely not correct. Range of speeds for supernova remnant is likely to be much larger, than we have on the sun.

Comment: The Sun produces a blackbody spectrum because it is *dense* and *opaque*, not because of Doppler shifts. (Very cold objects produce blackbody spectra, despite the fact that their constituent particles are moving *very* slowly.)

Answer (score -1):

The difference is that in the Nebulae you have black background for your hydrogen lines emission, and you can observe this easily with very simple imaging techniques (typically, 3.5-8nm pass-band filters do just fine).

On the sun you have "white" background - black body emission from deep levels of the sun. Hydrogen lines are now visible as absorption lines - darker than background. But in order to see them with enough contrast on this white background you need much more sophisticated equipment - ~0.1nm pass-band filters, otherwise there is too little contrast to see anything.

So the answer is simple: Hydrogen emission lines on black background have much larger contrast than absorption lines on white background. Hence emission lines in nebulae are much easier to observe and photograph.